# Integration Testing in CICD Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a spring boot project[App-Server], for which I want to test.
I have created Mock Server docker image also hosted in AWS/Dockerhub for the same.
Also I have used Rest Assured for API Testing. For this also docker image is available in AWS/Dockerhub.

Now before creating docker image for App-Server, I want to perform integration testing where I want Dockerfile.test for App-Server to load and create docker image, then on jenkins I want first the App-Server docker image to load, then Mock-Server docker image to load and after that the Rest Assured to load and do the testing which can be done via mvn test. Once the test is successful, I want to create the final docker image for App-Server.

Can this be done via Jenkins or AWS.

Answer (score 0):

`tldr:` You have to create docker images, deploy to test system, and run e.g. integration test, before creating final release version.

`Detailed answer:` I suggest you to get a closer look with you use-case at git branching model e.g. [gitflow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and [CI/CD](https://docs.docker.com/ci-cd/best-practices/) including containerization of an application.

Let's look it with the following scenario. Once you fixed e.g. a bug in release branch and pushed to git, your e.g. *Release Jenkins* job pulls it and build docker images with the version of e.g. release candidate `v1.0.0-rc1`. Then you must promote/deploy built release candidate version to your e.g. **release reference system** with mocking systems (e.g. you can use aws for this) as it is illustrated [here](https://docs.docker.com/ci-cd/best-practices/), i.e. inner loop. You only created final release version of e.g. `1.0.0` when test are completed successfully and deploy to e.g. production system, i.e. *Outer loop*.